# EPIserver no CSS for the UI Admin section

Tags: asp.net, web-config, episerver

After moving a EPI6 site to my local machine and reconfiguring it for IIS7.5 (instead of IIS6) i have a problem.

The UI Admin/Edit backend has no CSS. I suspected this was due to the virtual path mapping and i found that they where all mapped to %ProgramFiles% but on my local machine EPI is installed on %ProgramFiles(86)%. So i changed it and made sure all physical paths worked. They did.

So i felt smart and expected the CSS to load properly but no change happened.

I have tried ctrl F5 to see if its a caching problem, i have restarted the IISExpress. But still no CSS.

Any tips on something i might have forgotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this. 
It was not a problem of rights, but rather a configuration error. When uppgrading fom using IIS6 to IIS7.5 i forgot changing in the Web.Config:

IIS6 version

```
  <location path="App_Themes/Default" />
```

to:

IIS7.5 version

```
 <location path="App_Themes/Default">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <clear />
                <add name="wildcard" path="*" verb="*" type="EPiServer.Web.StaticFileHandler, EPiServer" />
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Check using Firebug Net-tab or equivalent F12 web browser tool to see exactly which paths don't respond correctly.
- Check permissions on disk for the Program Files directories in questions.
- Compare Web.config to a default EPiServer IIS7 web.config to see that you have all handlers in the correct place.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the IIS have no specific rights declared for the EPI framework programfiles. Im not sure which user i should give the rights to. I have given full access to "IIS_IUSRS" but ive heard IIS7.5 uses NETWORKSSERVICE. Strangely, that user is not found when i try to give it full access over the EPI directories.

Comment: I found and gave rights to NETWORKSSERIVCE (its a localized swedish version so i used the swedish name). But still the same problem.